# Issue drawing multiple Images on Canvas with drawImage()

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I just cannot get this to work for me.

I'm trying to use drawImage() to draw multiple images to a canvas. I feel like I'm massively overlooking something little.

It should draw 18 cards to the canvas. It'll start 50px in from the left, and down from the top, and draw each card 100w*150h. There should be 25px between each card image. Canvas dimensions are set to 825w * 600h.

Trying to accomplish this with plain Javascript (no jQuery). Any help is appreciated.

The image is how it is currently drawing to my canvas.
[image: How it is outputting to the canvas currently.]

```
// Draw the cards to the canvas.
function drawCards()
{
    // Starting positions.
    var x = 50;
    var y = 50;

    // Counter that will hold current card position.
    var cardCount = 0;

    var img = new Image(100, 150);

    // How many rows.
    for (var row = 0; row < 3; row++)
    {
        // How many columns.
        for (var column = 0; column < 6; column++)
        {
            // Store the current card.
            var card = memoryDeck[cardCount];

            // Check if the card is flipped, if it is set an image with url to face card.
            if (card.flipped == true)
            {
                img.onload = function() {
                    ctx.drawImage(this, x, y, 100, 150);
                }
                img.src = card.faceImage;
            }
            // Otherwise set image url to back of card.
            else
            {
                img.onload = function() {
                    ctx.drawImage(this, x, y, 100, 150);
                }
                img.src = card.backImage;           
            }

            // Increase the x position (the width of a card, plus the space in between), and the current card position being stored.
            x += 125; 
            cardCount++;
        }

        // We are on a new row, reset the column card position and increase the row card position.
        x = 50;
        y += 175;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS variables are not scoped to block, they are scoped to function. So when img.onload accesses `x` and `y`, they reference the final values of x and y.
 To create block-scoped variables, use let statements or IIFEs.

```
// Draw the cards to the canvas.
function drawCards()
{
    // Starting positions.
    var x = 50;
    var y = 50;

    // Counter that will hold current card position.
    var cardCount = 0;

    var img = new Image(100, 150);

    // How many rows.
    for (var row = 0; row < 3; row++)
    {
        // How many columns.
        for (var column = 0; column < 6; column++)
        {
            // Store the current card.
            var card = memoryDeck[cardCount];

            // Check if the card is flipped, if it is set an image with url to face card.
            if (card.flipped == true)
            {
                (function(x, y) {
                img.onload = function() {
                    ctx.drawImage(this, x, y, 100, 150);
                }
                img.src = card.faceImage;
                })(x, y);
            }
            // Otherwise set image url to back of card.
            else
            {
                (function(x, y) {
                img.onload = function() {
                    ctx.drawImage(this, x, y, 100, 150);
                }
                img.src = card.backImage; 
                })(x, y);          
            }

            // Increase the x position (the width of a card, plus the space in between), and the current card position being stored.
            x += 125; 
            cardCount++;
    }

        // We are on a new row, reset the column card position and increase the row card position.
        x = 50;
        y += 175;
     }

}
```

A similar simpler problem is this:

```html
READ THE SOURCE CODE!
<script>
  function demo1() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(){alert('i === ' + i)}, i * 200);
  }
  // i === 6
    
    
  // You expect this to happen:
  // [alerts "i === 1"]
  // [alerts "i === 2"]
  // [alerts "i === 3"]
  // [alerts "i === 4"]
  // [alerts "i === 5"]
  
  // What actually happens:
  // [alerts "i === 6"]
  // [alerts "i === 6"]
  // [alerts "i === 6"]
  // [alerts "i === 6"]
  // [alerts "i === 6"]
  // [alerts "i === 6"]
  }
</script>
<button onclick="demo1();">Demo 1 </button>
<script>
  function demo2(){
    for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
      // IIFE for the win!
      (function(i) {
      setTimeout(function(){alert('i === ' + i)}, i * 200);
      })(i);
    }
    
    // Expected:
    // [alerts "i === 0"]
    // [alerts "i === 1"]
    // [alerts "i === 2"]
    // [alerts "i === 3"]
    // [alerts "i === 4"]
    // [alerts "i === 5"]
    
    // Actual:
    // [alerts "i === 0"]
    // [alerts "i === 1"]
    // [alerts "i === 2"]
    // [alerts "i === 3"]
    // [alerts "i === 4"]
    // [alerts "i === 5"]
  }
 </script>
<button onclick="demo2();">Demo 2</button>
```

Comment: This solved half of my problem. Thanks! I still need to figure out why it is only drawing the last image though... :/

Comment: Looks like I didn't apply this completely. Used this and made slight adjustments and managed to fix the whole thing. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The given answer is problematic as it declaring function calls within a loop. This pattern of declaration is dangerous and can lead to memory leaks if you do not understand closure. The method used to overcome the scope problem is also very inefficient. And the code will not work as there is only one image being created, and each time the src is set the previous loading src is canceled and the process started again.

Also creating anonymous functions makes it harder to debug your code as any errors will create hard to follow traces, and profiling will also be hard to read. Always name the functions, and always place functions at the top of their scope.

```
function drawCards(){
    // declare all variables and functions
    var row, column, src, cardIndex, card;
    function loadThenDisplayImage (src, x, y) {
        var image;
        function onImageload () {
             ctx.drawImage(this, x, y, cardW, cardH);
        }
        image = new Image(cardW, cardH);
        image.src = src;
        image.onload = onImageLoad;
    }
    // define constants and variables.
    const left = 50;
    const top = 50;
    const cardW = 100;
    const cardH = 150;
    const xSpacing = 25;
    const ySpacing = 25;
    cardIndex= 0;

    // function logic 
    for (row = 0; row < 3; row += 1) {
        for (column = 0; column < 6; column += 1) {
            card = memoryDeck[cardIndex += 1];
            scr = card.flipped ? card.faceImage : card.backImage;
            loadThenDisplayImage(  // long function call best split for readbility
                src, 
                left + (cardW + xSpacing) * column, 
                top + (cardH + ySpacing) * row
            );
        }
     }
}
```